# How to add level to column to result MDX in mondrian

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I have the following table created by the following MDX

```
SELECT
{
    [Measures].numTickets 
}ON COLUMNS,
{
Descendants(DateCreacion.Children, DateCreacion.Month) 
}ON ROWS
FROM tickets
```

[image]

The thing is that i want to add another column to the numTickets but every time i add a dimension to the column, i get an empty column.

```
select {[Clinica].Children} ON COLUMNS,
  {Descendants([DateCreacion].Children, [DateCreacion.YQMD].[Month])} ON ROWS
from [tickets]
```

[image]

How would i show the same data as the first picture but in the second format?

```
<Schema name="New Schema1">
  <Cube name="tickets" visible="true" cache="true" enabled="true">
    <Table name="fact">
    </Table>
    <Dimension type="TimeDimension" visible="true" foreignKey="fecha_tickets_id" name="DateCreacion">
      <Hierarchy name="YQMD" visible="true" hasAll="true">
        <Table name="dim_fecha_creacion_tickets" alias="">
        </Table>
        <Level name="Year" visible="true" column="a&#241;o" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeYears">
        </Level>
        <Level name="Quarter" visible="true" column="cuarto" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeQuarters">
        </Level>
        <Level name="Month" visible="true" column="mes" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeMonths">
        </Level>
        <Level name="Day" visible="true" column="dia" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeDays">
          <Property name="date_iso" column="date_iso" type="Numeric">
          </Property>
        </Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>
    <Dimension type="StandardDimension" visible="true" foreignKey="clinica_id" name="Clinica">
      <Hierarchy name="New Hierarchy 0" visible="true" hasAll="true">
        <Table name="dim_posicion" alias="">
        </Table>
        <Level name="Posicion" visible="true" column="sigla" type="String" uniqueMembers="false">
        </Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>
    <Measure name="numTickets" column="idTicket" datatype="Numeric" aggregator="count" visible="true">
    </Measure>
  </Cube>
</Schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

When adding the `[Clinica].Children` to the columns, you removed the measures.
You probably want to keep them, using a cross join, which can be stated using the `*` operator in MDX: Either

```
select {[Clinica].Children} 
       *
       { [Measures].numTickets }
       ON COLUMNS,
...
```

or

```
select { [Measures].numTickets } 
       *
       {[Clinica].Children}
       ON COLUMNS,
...
```

depending on the order of columns you want to see.